# How to implement a Timer on JBoss 4.2.2

Tags: jboss, timer

How can I implement a timer on JBoss 4.2.2 in a vendor independent way.

Requirements:

- trigger logic in a defined interval
- start the timer at startup
- no dependencies to JBoss specific libraries / functionality
- do not use a servlet to start the timer

But I see only this possibilites:

1. Implement the interface org.jboss.varia.scheduler.Schedulable
2. Use ejb3 combined with a MBean (MBean for starting the timer)
3. Use javax.management.timer.Timer as MBean

Answer (score 0):

Ok my solution at the end was this:

```
@Service(objectName = "scheduler.test:service=CommonSchedulerTimer")
@Remote(Scheduler.class)
public class SchedulerTimerBean implements Scheduler, SchedulerManagement {

@Timeout
public void timeoutHandler(Timer timer) {
```

**What is it:**

- Stateless Session Bean
- Timer Bean
- MBean

**What is not vendor independent:**

- the service annotation

But I didn't found a vendor independent way to access the ejb from a separate MBean. The Problem was the order of initalitation of beans, i couldn't configure, that the MBean must be loaded after the EJB in clean way.